# can't install network package

Tags: haskell, cabal, ffi

I have the network package already installed. When I try to reinstall it (for use with cabal-dev, for example), it won't compile. If I `cabal unpack network` and then try to build that, I get the output below. I am guessing that this broke because I upgraded an Ubuntu dependency. I upgraded to Ubuntu 11.04 in hopes that it would help; it didn't. Also installed libghc6-network-dev in case that would make things link correctly; it didn't. I am on ghc-7.0.2, and just tried ghc-7.0.3 also. Currently trying installing the latest haskell platform from source... Any help appreciated- this is completely killing my haskell hacking!

```
Socket.hsc: In function ‘main’:
Socket.hsc:1033:5: error: invalid application of ‘sizeof’ to incomplete type ‘struct ucred’ 
Socket.hsc:1033:5: error: invalid application of ‘sizeof’ to incomplete type ‘struct ucred’ 
Socket.hsc:1033:5: error: invalid application of ‘sizeof’ to incomplete type ‘struct ucred’ 
Socket.hsc:1039:5: error: invalid use of undefined type ‘struct ucred’
Socket.hsc:1040:5: error: invalid use of undefined type ‘struct ucred’
Socket.hsc:1041:5: error: invalid use of undefined type ‘struct ucred’
compiling dist/build/Network/Socket_hsc_make.c failed (exit code 1)
```

command was:

```
/usr/bin/gcc -c dist/build/Network/Socket_hsc_make.c -o dist/build/Network/Socket_hsc_make.o -fno-stack-protector -fno-stack-protector -D__GLASGOW_HASKELL__=700 -Dlinux_BUILD_OS -Dlinux_HOST_OS -Dx86_64_BUILD_ARCH -Dx86_64_HOST_ARCH -Iinclude -I/usr/local/lib/ghc-7.0.2/unix-2.4.2.0/include -Idist/build/autogen -include dist/build/autogen/cabal_macros.h -Idist/build/autogen -include dist/build/autogen/cabal_macros.h -Idist/build/autogen -include dist/build/autogen/cabal_macros.h -Idist/build/autogen -include dist/build/autogen/cabal_macros.h -I/usr/local/lib/ghc-7.0.2/bytestring-0.9.1.10/include -Idist/build/autogen -include dist/build/autogen/cabal_macros.h -I/usr/local/lib/ghc-7.0.2/base-4.3.1.0/include -Idist/build/autogen -include dist/build/autogen/cabal_macros.h -Idist/build/autogen -include dist/build/autogen/cabal_macros.h -Idist/build/autogen -include dist/build/autogen/cabal_macros.h -I/usr/local/lib/ghc-7.0.2/include -Idist/build/autogen -include dist/build/autogen/cabal_macros.h -I/usr/local/lib/ghc-7.0.2/include -Idist/build/autogen -include dist/build/autogen/cabal_macros.h -I/usr/local/lib/ghc-7.0.2/include/
```

---

Here is my gcc version:

```
/usr/bin/gcc --version
gcc (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.5.2-8ubuntu4) 4.5.2
```

Comment: Works for me on Ubuntu 10.10 with gcc 4.4.5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I upgraded to ghc 7.0.3 and then installed the 7.0.3 haskell platform from source, and now everything is working. Not that I understand why :)

Answer (score 1):

If I remember correctly there was a problem with older versions of cabal-install. Try to install the latest version

```
cabal install cabal-install-0.10.2
```